# Does archiving mailings do anything in particular?

Tags: civimail

CiviMail has an option to archive mailings (when browsing mailings).

Does changing the status to archived have any concrete impact on mailings, such as cleaning up information in the database? If not, what's the main use case for it?

Comment: good question. was hoping to find an answer here!

Comment: Still don't have a good answer for this here. Someone out there know or will I need to dig into the code?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from the code and from trying it out, archiving a mailing will mark a mailing as archived. And that's it. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

In terms of deleting a mailing, it'll remove the mailing report and other data, but it'll keep the activities associated with contacts, which might be useful for some reporting.

Comment: I thought it might remove from the include previous mailing but it does not. So not seeing any functionality really behind this.

Answer (score 1):

In my first Civi site (Joomla), I didn't archive my sent emails.  Then, when I tried to send a new email, the old, sent email would be re-sent in the same cron job as well.  CiviDesk told me the fix was to archive sent emails, and I have been doing it without fail ever since.  The problem has not recurred.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  I'll note that this is atypical behavior though; I suspect there was a bug at the time that no longer applies, or perhaps is related to customizations.  Typically this would not happen.