# How do I manage a database with millions of mail recipient records when searching on opens or click throughs?

Tags: email, performance

We are working with a group that sends tens of thousands of mailings on a weekly basis so the `civicrm_mailing_recipient` (and related tables) have millions of records.

They also want to track opens and click throughs. The problem is that it takes eons (like over 5 minutes) to search these tables.

I think the answer is to purge this old data.

But just in case, I'm wondering if:

- There are optimizing tips to make these searches go faster?
- There are any extensions to help automate the purging of old recipient data? It seems that [archiving email](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/does-archiving-mailings-do-anything-in-particular/22282#22282) doesn't touch this data
- Any other tips?

Thanks!